# Flutter Swipe in Any Direction to Reload Current Screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the user to be able to reload the current screen by swiping in any direction.  Now, I've tried to implement this with nearly all of the gesture detection widgets I could find, but I think they are slightly unreliable.

For example, using the built-in GestureDetector or the pub packages that utilize it, the swipe gesture registers maybe 7 times out of 10.  If I have a print function that registers on the swipe, in the console I see "view port action *direction*" every time but the print "swiped" 7 out of 10 times.

So my question is, how can I set this up where the swipe is registered every time?  I'm thinking of the swiping responsiveness of the dismissive or pageview widgets.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

   void _onVerticalSwipe(SwipeDirection direction) {
     setState(() {
       if (direction == SwipeDirection.up) {
         //print('Swiped up!');
         Navigator.push(
             context,
             PageTransition(
                 type: PageTransitionType.downToUp, child: MyHomePage()));
       } else {
        // print('Swiped down!');
         Navigator.push(
             context,
             PageTransition(
                 type: PageTransitionType.upToDown, child: MyHomePage()));
       }
     });
   }

   void _onHorizontalSwipe(SwipeDirection direction) {
     setState(() {
       if (direction == SwipeDirection.left) {
        // print('Swiped left!');
         Navigator.push(
             context,
             PageTransition(
                 type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: MyHomePage()));
       } else {
        // print('Swiped right!');
         Navigator.push(
             context,
             PageTransition(
                 type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: MyHomePage()));
       }
     });
   }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleGestureDetector(
      onVerticalSwipe: _onVerticalSwipe,
      onHorizontalSwipe: _onHorizontalSwipe,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: FittedBox(child: Text('Text'))),
                Expanded(child: FittedBox(child: Text('Image'))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you wrap the `Scaffold` in `GestureDetector`? If not the hitbox for the `GestureDetector` is only inclusive of whatever is inside the Scaffold, not the whole screen itself. Another thing to be careful of is to make sure your scaffold is opaque. If it is transparent for whatever reason it will not register the gestures since you technically swiping over nothing.

Comment: Try sharing some code if this isn't helpful, hard for me to help without knowing whats wrong haha.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks so much for your reply.  Yes I have tried wrapping in Scaffold.  I posted code for you.  It's using 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart' for transition animation and 'package:simple_gesture_detector/simple_gesture_detector.dart' for the swipe detection.

Comment: I've played with the settings like animation speed in the transitions plugin, and have also played with threshold levels in the simple gesture detector.  No config perfects the swipe.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question by tweaking some information I found online.  The following is providing a responsive and reliable 4 way swiping action! (Note: I'm using the page transitions package for transition animation.)

```dart
var initial_x;
var distance_x;

var initial_y;
var distance_y;

GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
        initial_x = details.globalPosition.dx;
        initial_y = details.globalPosition.dy;
      },
      onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        distance_x = details.globalPosition.dx - initial_x;
        distance_y = details.globalPosition.dy - initial_y;
      },
      onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
       
        initial_x = 0.0;
        initial_y = 0.0;

        var x_abs = distance_x.abs();
        var y_abs = distance_y.abs();

        if (x_abs > y_abs) {
          if (distance_x > 20) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: MainSwiper()));
          }
          if (distance_x < -20) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: MainSwiper()));
          }
        } else if (y_abs > x_abs) {
          if (distance_y > 20) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.upToDown, child: MainSwiper()));
          }
          if (distance_y < -20) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.downToUp, child: MainSwiper()));
          }
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
```